# C++ Code Output explanation 4

Tags: c++

I'am newbie in c++, can anybody explain the output of this program:

```
int main()
{
    int m=96, j=49; 
    m = (printf("what's up"), printf(" programmers ? ")); 
    printf("%d", m); 
    return 0; 
}
```

output :

> what's up programmers ? 15

Comment: Read about "What does `printf` return" and "What does comma operator do"

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your profile shows that you are asking questions in all languages at random. Please spend more time to understand these languages and read good books. That will also help improve the quality of questions. Good Luck.

Comment: And it's "I am" or "I'm", not "I'am".

Answer (score 1):

From [en.cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf):

> ```
> int printf( const char* format, ... );
> ```
>
> **Return value**
> 1-2) Number of characters written if successful or negative value if an error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

There are 15 characters in `programmers ?`. `printf` returns the number of characters written.

In this line:

```
m = (printf("what's up"), printf(" programmers ? "));
```

These functions will be evaluated, and the last expression will be returned. Therefore `printf` will be called twice, and the return value of the last `printf` will be stored in `m`.